# Could we query community pages or lighting applications built from app builder through SOQL

Tags: lightning

Could we query community pages or lighting applications built from app builder through SOQL?

I tried to query the new built applications through this SOQL statements.
But didn't find any.
Or which table I should query for the lightning applications/pages created by `app builder`

```
    SELECT
        ID,
        ApiVersion,
        Description,
        DeveloperName,
        IsDeleted,
        Language,
        MasterLabel,
        NamespacePrefix
    FROM AuraDefinitionBundle ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

[image: inline]

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for **[`FlexiPage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flexipage.htm)**. You can query this object via the `Tooling API` or `Metadata API`. For example, this query works in the `Query Editor` if you check the `Use Tooling API` option:

```
SELECT Id, Description, DeveloperName, EntityDefinitionId FROM FlexiPage
```

Comment: SELECT Id, Description, DeveloperName, EntityDefinitionId FROM FlexiPage, `INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'FlexiPage' is not supported.`??

Comment: @Dummy You can't run tooling queries natively in Apex. Notice how I recommend to run this query. If you want to run it from Apex, you will have to manually call out to the Tooling API. There are many Q&A threads on this site about how to do so.

Comment: @AdrianLarson are you sure it works for community site pages? I just created a site page in builder and none of those pages returned. Flexipage seems to be those pages related to objects.